# jQuery video clicking image to action video play (with placeholder on YT player)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to click a thumbnail image in one div to play an embedded youtube video in another div (embedded as iframe) as a full size video. I've gotten that far, but instead of the YT player showing when the page loads i need a static image to replace it. I'm very new to jquery but have created the code from a few other answers on here so am a bit stuck on how to do the replacement image along with the rest of it. any help would be amazing.

any chance of any of this working on image maps instead of divs?

```
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">    
<div class="video_case">
   <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0" width="560" height="315" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="video_wrapper">
   <ul>
      <li class="video_thumbnail">
          <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1&amp;controls=0" title="" class="video-1"><img src="/ProductImages_Display/PREVIEW/2/5172_31188_10523.jpg" border="0" width="180" height="268" style="border: 0;" /></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[
    $(function() {
      $(".video-1").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".video_case iframe").prop("src", $(event.currentTarget).attr("href"));
      });    
    });
  // ]]>
  </script>
</p>
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you want to happen. Is this close? http://jsfiddle.net/c87k9/

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation - id like to click on a small image which would trigger a youtube embedded video to play in another div (larger format - not full screen). i would want a different image to display over the video player when the video was not activated (i.e on page load or after video has finished playing) - really appreciate any help i can get on this. Not sure that previous example is what i'm after (which is to be expected given my poor requirements.) thanks